# When is cone homeomorphic to cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is the problem: Find a non-trivial example of a (linear connected) space X so that cone over X is homeomorphic to cylinder over X. Trivial examples are one point set and empty set.
I have absolutely no idea.My friend says it's an interval, then cone is triangle and cylinder is a rectangle, but I don't agree that they are homeomorphic. Am I wrong?

Comment: So the cylinder is $X \times I$ while the cone is $(X \times I )/ (X \times \{0\})$.

Answer (score 3):

For a *closed* interval, the cone and cylinders are a *closed* triangle and rectangle, and those are homeomorphic because either is homeomorphic to a closed disk.

For an *open* interval, however, you get into trouble. Then then the cone contains an isolated boundary point but the cylinder doesn't.

For a *half-open* interval there's still trouble, because the boundary of the cone is a half-open interval but the boundary of the cylinder is a closed interval.